# Spring boot-multi module fat jar

Tags: spring-boot, executable-jar, target, multi-module, fatjar

Unable to create a fat jar of a spring boot multi-module project which includes jars of all child modules. The single fat jar needs to be executable. Tried with maven-shade-plugin and spring-boot-maven-plugin. It does not generate a single fat jar rather generates multiple module jars.

Answer (score 1):

try apply repackage goal in the top-level module

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>repackage</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
```